# Merging multiple polygons to one polygon in shapefile

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, openlayers-2, merge

How to merge multiple polygons to one polygon in the shapefile using openlayers and geoserver.

ie in the portal if user selects the multiple polygons in the same boundary, it has to merge as a single polygon

As shown in the figure below[image]

Comment: What research have you do on this? where are you stuck? Please see this post on steps to improve your question: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/framing-asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange

Answer (score 1):

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) has an extension that provides [Web Processing Service (WPS)](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wps/index.html) methods. One of these is the `geo:union` process which will do exactly what you need.

You need to construct some XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>geo:union</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>geom</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json"><![CDATA[Some JSON Here]]></wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

With a JSON representation of your polygons in the CDATA block and POST it to GeoServer, it will return a JSON representation of the union of the polygons you sent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please send me an example code.

Comment: that is the example code that you need, just insert your JSON and post

Comment: which json data i have to post? please mention that. when user selects the multiple polygons (selection may be rectangular select or by click) it has to merge as single polygon.so please tell me which data(json) i have to post.

Comment: the JSON that represents the selected polygons

Comment: how to call this service in openlayers 3 wfs-t